# how to accept only specific “subnets” using iptables?

Tags: linux, iptables

I have to limit access to 8080 port and allow only some IPs and specific subnets.  Is it possible, can you please help?

**I enabled filtering for IPs but I couldn't find how to accept *subnets?***

```
sudo /sbin/iptables -N CHN_PNTS
sudo /sbin/iptables -A CHN_PNTS --src 182.10.10.109  -j ACCEPT  
sudo /sbin/iptables -A CHN_PNTS --src 182.20.35.110  -j ACCEPT 
sudo /sbin/iptables -A CHN_PNTS --src 182.20.55.15   -j ACCEPT 
sudo /sbin/iptables -A CHN_PNTS -j DROP 
sudo /sbin/iptables -I INPUT -m tcp -p tcp --dport 8080 -j CHN_PNTS
```

**subnets that i want to accept;**

```
182.24.137.0/24
182.24.138.0/23
```

Thanks
Erdal

Comment: `--src 182.24.137.0/24`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You just use CIDR notation like in your question

```
sudo /sbin/iptables -A CHN_PNTS --src 182.24.137.0/24   -j ACCEPT
sudo /sbin/iptables -A CHN_PNTS --src 182.24.138.0/23   -j ACCEPT
```

Remember to place them before your

```
sudo /sbin/iptables -A CHN_PNTS -j DROP
```

so that they are actioned correctly.

Answer (score 4):

Subnet specifications are acceptable in the source.

```
sudo /sbin/iptables -A CHN_PNTS --src 182.24.137.0/24 -j ACCEPT 
sudo /sbin/iptables -A CHN_PNTS --src 182.24.138.0/23 -j ACCEPT
```